# Svn to git: How to deal with our not-standard, probably wrongly branched svn

Tags: svn, git, branch

Our current svn structure looks like this:

```
trunk
-- project
-- projectDao
-- projectResources
branches
-- project-1.0
-- projectDao-1.0
-- projectResources-1.0
-- project-2.0
-- projectDao-2.0
-- projectResources-2.0
tags
-- project-1.0.0
-- ...
```

To make things worse project-1.0 was branched from project projectDao-1.0 from projectDao (each in seperate move commits). Idealy it would have been like this.

This is the commit log:

```
trunk
-- project
-- projectDao
-- projectResources
branches
-- 1.0
---- project
---- projectDao
---- projectResources
-- 2.0
---- project
---- projectDao
---- projectResources
tags
--1.0.0
----project
---- ...
```

And this is the way it makes sense. And we should then have branched from trunk to 1.0 instead of 2 different commits.

We however want to switch to git now (permanently) and I am at a loss how i should start with this.

I don't really get how i should do this. When i just git clone my repository with standard layout I get something this.

```
* master
  remotes/project-1.0
  remotes/project-1.0@3
  remotes/project-2.0
  remotes/project-2.0@10
  remotes/projectDao-1.0
  remotes/projectDao-1.0@4
  remotes/projectDao-2.0
  remotes/projectDao-2.0@11
  remotes/projectResources-1.0
  remotes/projectResources-1.0@5
  remotes/projectResources-2.0
  remotes/projectResources-2.0@12
  remotes/tags/project-1.0.0
  remotes/tags/projectDao-1.0.0
  remotes/tags/projectResources-1.0.0
  remotes/trunk
```

This is what gitg generates

[image: This is what gitg generates]

I don't know how I can use rebase to get this right like:

```
* master
  remotes/1.0
  remotes/2.0
  remotes/tags/1.0.0
  remotes/trunk
```

Comment: Please type "git branch -a" and post the complete output of that command in your question.

Comment: It seems that you have exported and imported several times into git, is this true? For example the master seems to be a sub tree of its own, so is the "green" etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the imported branches to directories in a 1.0 branch. Furtheron you don't mention if this is a permanent migration or a git-svn checkout while you maintain your svn repository.

In case this is just a git-svn checkout and the goal is to keep working with the original SVN as central repository, I would just do a checkout without using the standard layout switch and work in the directories of SVN. It's a bit dirtier, but you don't have problems while pushing back to SVN.

In case you want to transform your repository, add a commit to all branches putting the contents of that branch into a directory in the root, to merge the branches together afterwards. You won't loose the SVN history with the old branch structure in your GIT history, but the future will be new-style.

Only in case you want to transform all of the history you will have to create directories and rebase.

Comment: We would migrate permanantly. However this is quite new for me so I don't really understand how you can do this: _add a commit to all branches putting the contents of that branch into a directory in the root, to merge the branches together afterward_ . It is not really needed to transform all the history.

Comment: To get a 1.0 and 2.0 branch (for 3.0 and onward you can just branch the master off to a 3.0 branch): on the branches of these (say, Project-2.0, ProjectDao-2.0 and ProjectResources-2.0, or a working copy of these 3 branches) you create a directory Project in the first, ProjectDao in the second and ProjectResources in the third corresponding to the master, and move all documents to those respectively, then commit, then merge together into the new 2.0 branch.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to rebase these branches as you see fit with git. As long as you can get the complete history from svn to git it's a piece of cake to create branch 1.0 and 2.0 from any commit you see fit and continue from there to build up any structure you want.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, I don't understand how to do this. I added the branch structure I currently have in the first post.

Comment: It looks a bit weird with the naming "remotes/project-1.0" etc (it almost looks like a remote branch, which would look something like "remotes/origin/master"), but I guess this is what happens when you convert from svn to git.